# How do you convert an existing webforms application to a hybird webforms/mvc application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms

I have a ASP .NET Webforms application running via Visual Studio 2010 and ASP.NET Development Server. I'm trying to run a few using Razor views (.cshtml). When I try to browse to the page, I get the following error:

```
This type of page is not served. 
Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been 
explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.cshtml' may be incorrect.
```

Comment: It's not possible at this moment. It seems you'll be able to do it on future asp.net versions

Comment: Do you mean it's not possible within the development environment, or do you mean not at all, not even using IIS or IIS Express? I ask because I've seen various blog posts showing how to mix Web Forms and Razor pages.

Comment: Sorry, ignore my comment, I was confused.

Answer (score 2):

I'm kinda of reaching here on understanding your question, but based off your comment, are you trying to add MVC 3 to an already existing WebForms app?

If so, just add Hanselman's AddMVC3ToWebForms nuget package.

Comment: I've done that, but I still get the resulting errors in my question.

Comment: But yes this is exactly what I'm asking about

Comment: How familiar are you with MVC3? You are aware that you navigate to the controller, and not the actual .cshtml page, right?